# Xcode build failed: Static setter referenced from UI test class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to update a static variable in the setup of the UI test class, and the build fails with the following log:

[image]

In my application I am able to set the value of this boolean from a non-static context through the setter. But not in the setup before the UI test, why?

Comment: Is your `CallIn.CallIn.Settings` class added to UITests target?

Comment: no it's not, but it also should not be target of the UI test, I am using import testable, to add project files to UI tests, but according to other docs it should not be included in the target for UI tests